# Measuring the network distance between two sets of nodes containing isolates

Tags: graph-theory

I need to measure the mean length of shortest paths between two sets of nodes in a graph. The problem is that some nodes are isolates and therefore infinitely distant from all other nodes. How to produce a meaningful distance statistic between the two groups while dealing with the isolates in a principled way?

```
set.seed(1); G <- sample_gnp(50, 1/30)
V(G)$color <- "green"
set.seed(1); V(G)[sample(1:vcount(G),length(V(G))/2) ]$color <- "red"
set.seed(1); plot(G)
```

[image]

The code below calculates the distance between the red and green groups only for connected nodes.

```
distance_red_green <- list()
for(i in 1:length(V(g)[s])){
  x <- shortest_paths(g, V(g)[V(G)$color == "red"][i], V(g)[V(G)$color == "green"])
  a <- sapply(x$vpath, function(y) length(y)-1)
  a <- ifelse(a == 0, NA, a)
  b <- mean(a, na.rm = T)
  distance_red_green[[i]] <- b
}

> mean(unlist(distance_red_green), na.rm = T)
[1] 5.421153
```

One way of addressing this issue is assigning a large distance to pairs of nodes that cannot reach each other. But this is arbitrary. Any takes on alternatives? (I'm using R to implement this, but the question is conceptual).